# get and set css style into var

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am just begginer. I am trying to get font size of the element into variable. After that I would like to set font size of another element using this variable.

I have been looking for the solution for 12 hours and found nothing. I would be grateful for any tips. Thanks in advance.

My code is below.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

        var OldFont = jQuery('.mhmainnav').find('li').find('a').css("font-size");

        var windowTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowTop > 280) {

            jQuery('.mh-main-nav').find('li').find('a').css("font-size", "12px");

        } else {

            jQuery('.mh-main-nav').find('li').find('a').css("font-size", OldFont);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your html code  also so it will be help full  to answer

Comment: First you look for `.mhmainnav`, later for `.mh-main-nav`. Also, just store the `a` tags in a variable, no need to search for the same tags every time. Also note that the `find()` calls are completely unnessecary, you could just do `jQuery('.mh-main-nav li a').css()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I would change is moving the old font to outside your scroll, otherwise when you change the font-size to 12px, `OldFont` will get overwritten next time you scroll.

Maybe probably cache your anchor selector too for better performance

Also check your `mhmainnav` selector - you change it to `mh-main-nav`

```js
var anchors = jQuery('.mhmainnav').find('a'), // if you are reusing this in the scroll, cache it here for better performance
  OldFont = anchors.css("font-size"); // set this before the scroll as it shouldn't change once set

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowTop = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

  if (windowTop > 280) {
    anchors.css("font-size", "12px");
  } else {
    anchors.css("font-size", OldFont);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var OldFont = parseInt($('p').css("font-size"));
        alert(OldFont);
    });
});
```

This will alert the font-size, now you cane use it as require.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this following HTML and Jquery snippets

HTML code

```
<ul class="mhmainav">
  <li>
    <a href="" style="font-size:20px;">aaa</a>
    <a href="" style="font-size:25px;">aaa</a>
    <a href="" style="font-size:27px;">aaa</a>
    <a href="" style="font-size:30px;">aaa</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
var oldFont= $('.mhmainav li  a');
$.each(oldFont, function(index, value){
    $(value).css('font-size'); // get font-size value
    $(value).css('font-size','20px'); //set font-size value; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var size = $(YOUR STYLE PARENT SELECTOR).css('font-size');
```

Then:-

```
$(YOUR STYLE Target Selector).css({ 'font-size': size });
```

Hope this would help you :-)